Invalid conversion from string to decimal type when reading dgv cell
I have 2 DGVs, DGV1 is bound and DGV2 is unbound.
In DGV1 I load the Access database “parts” are over 7400
articles.
In DGV2 I load a .csv of the database “parts”.
This DGV2 is used for the inventory of our articles with the columns
“Old stock”, ‘New stock’, ‘Difference’.
This error message always appears if the next line in DGV2 does not yet have a new stock: Invalid conversion from string to decimal type.
Question:
How can I enter the new values from DGV2 in the “New stock” column?
to DGV1 column “Old stock” ?
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.TEILEBindingSource.EndEdit()

    Dim row As TeileDataSet.TEILERow

    For i = 0 To Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim dgvrow As DataGridViewRow = Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i)
        If (dgvrow IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (Not dgvrow.IsNewRow) Then
            'The PrimaryKey for this table is the LotId field
            row = TeileDataSet.TEILE.FindByID(dgvrow.Cells("IDTeileNR").Value)
            If row IsNot Nothing Then
                row("Old stock") = CDec(dgvrow.Cells("New stock").Value) ' **<---- Here comes error message: Invalid conversion from string to decimal type.**
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub


Debug on that line, and check the value of dgvrow.Cells("New stock").Value

Are you indicating that you expect dgvrow.Cells("New stock").Value to not be a valid number in this case, and you're looking to handle that case?  When you debug, what value does it have?  Can't you just check for that value before trying to convert it?  You might also look into things like Decimal.TryParse to handle parsing errors.

The value is probally Null, so CDec will throw an exception.
Since you use VBA in Access, it is best to check if the value is null.
There is a function for that.
row("Old stock")=Nz(dgvrow.Cells("New stock").Value,0)

Or make the column "Old stock" allow for null values.
Thanks for Craig for pointing me in the right direction.

IIf won't work.  It's a function, so all arguments are evaluated regardless of the true/false state of the first argument, meaning that is the value Is Nothing you'll still get an error from trying to convert in CDec.  It's also not appropriate to use in .NET.  There's a perfectly cromulent ternary operator now (If(x, y, z)) which will short-circuit and only evaluate the appropriate branch.

Also, a database NULL is not the same as a .NET null (or Nothing).

This is VBA not .NET. But you could be right about the Iif exception

I think it is also true in VBA that a database NULL is not necessarily the same as Nothing.

I also thought that, but can not find it in VBA. also VBA has different functions in Excel or Acces (or other office apps). DbNull.Value does exists in .Net and VB6 (or older).
